# DOCSIS modem only authenticated by MAC?

Tags: mac-address, spoofing

Is a DOCSIS modem only authenticated by the CMTS by a MAC address or are there any other AAA techniques? In that case, how do I prevent other customers from spoofing my modem's MAC address?

---

- *Cable Modem Initialization Wallchart* published by Cisco in 2005:

[image: Initialization_chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MAC address spoofing is possible, but a) requires knowledge of existing, valid, not used MAC address b) tools - not that widely available for cable modems as for ethernet routers.

Certificate based authentication and encryption is available (Baseline Privacy Inteface Plus - DOCSIS 1.1 and DOCSIS 2.0, Security in DOCSIS 3.0) - see http://bit.ly/1iJMbNM for some more details.